# recover a two element miss-placed binary search tree

Tags: c++, algorithm, binary-search-tree

Here is the problem:

Two elements of a binary search tree (BST) are swapped by mistake. Recover the tree without changing its structure.

My solution is store the pointer to node in a array during inorder traversal. Then traverse the array to find two miss positioned node, change their values. But I need O(n) space for allocating the array. My question is can I solve it with constant space?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to store the elements in an array. As two elements are swapped, one of them is a moved to an earlier position, thus it is greater than the element succeeding it in the inorder traversal. You don't need to store the elements in an array to find this - you need to only keep a context of one previous node. Analogously for the element moved to the right, it will be smaller than the element preceding it, thus you can again find it with keeping the same context(1 preceding element). As you suggested a single inorder traversal is enough to find the misplaced elements.